# Create comparable dice format from 2d array?

Tags: c++

So I have this problem that I want to make a 2d array to a dice format I can compare.
So if the 2d array is for example:

00100
02340
00500
00600

(0 = blank space)

would be:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GDzl.png)

So if you fold it in you get a dice. My problem is I need it in a format so I can compare if it's different from another dice.
For example:

00600
00500
04320
00100

Is the same as the other example, so I need it in a format where I can compare them. The rotation of numbers doesn't matter. Any ideas?

Comment: Matrix rotation?  Matrix *flipping*?  (Review your Linear Algebra for matrix operations)

Comment: Compare sides.  Take one side of die A and compare to all sides of die B.  Compare remaining sides.

Comment: "Compare sides. Take one side of die A and compare to all sides of die B. Compare remaining sides.", Thank you so much you just gave me an idea on how to make this in c++.